# How to repeat my Background image but with different image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a background image that scrolls to the left and repeats itself. However, I want it to repeat with another image that is in my drawable folder.

How can I do this?

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;   
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class Background {
    private Bitmap image;
    private int x, y, dx;

    public Background(Bitmap res) {
        dx = GamePanel.MoveSpeed;
        image = res;
    }

    public void update() {
        x += dx;
        if (x < -GamePanel.WIDTH) {
            x = 0;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, y, null);

        if (x < 0) {
            canvas.drawBitmap( image, x + GamePanel.WIDTH, y, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Background(Bitmap res) {
    dx = GamePanel.MoveSpeed;
    image = res;
}
```

As you can see, you call this method with the parameter "res".
Find where you call it and change the argument to the other image.